# Get length of static File array? Always come back null

Tags: java, arrays, static, processing

```
public PImage[] images;
public static File[] wallTiles = loadFolder("data/tiles/walls");
public static File[] floorTiles = loadFolder("data/tiles/floors");
public static int totalFiles = wallTiles.length+floorTiles.length;

private static File[] loadFolder(String string)
{
    File files = new File(string);

    File[] pngFiles = files.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName)
        {
            return fileName.endsWith(".png");
        };
    });
    return pngFiles;
}
```

Line 4, where totalFiles is assigned, always fails because wallTiles is null. I want to return the totalFiles in this class (called Art), so that I can do things like randomly choose a wall or floor texture for a game I'm working on. Thanks for listening.

Comment: ...and is it possible there arent any pngs in /walls ?

Comment: @radai, they're in there. Running as an applet works also, don't know if that helps.

Comment: "null" means no object.  Period.  You can't get anything out of null.  You need to investigate why you're getting a null, and at least one person has suggested you consult the javadoc (which describes the circumstances that will cause null to be returned).  Add some logging or use a debugger to check your assumptions.  For example, you can check the output of File.exists(), File.isDirectory(), etc.

Comment: What you guys are saying is true. Stepping through I am getting into the loadFolder method, but before pngFiles is returned it is null. When I debug as an applet it is populated. It must be in some way processing handles the data directory as a PApplet. Ugh, really it is supposed to come out as an applet through the eclipse plugin that I'm using (proclipsing), but it is not. I fear there are deeper problems that I'll have to consult the original authors of either proclipsing or processing or rewrite the way I handle the art.

Comment: Check your assumptions at every step in the program.  *Check the "files" object.*  check exists(), isDirectory(), canRead(), etc.  Read the javadoc, use any methods you think might shed light on the problem.  Remove your filter and see what impact that has.  Add some logging to the accept() method of your filter, etc.  There's plenty of stuff you can do to debug, before you get to the point where you need someone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

... Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory ...

So check if the directory exists and if there are files.

```
private static File[] loadFolder(String string)
{
    File files = new File(string);
    if(!files.exists() || !files.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println("Directory: "+string+" does not exists");       
        return new File[0];
    }

    File[] pngFiles = files.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName)
        {
            return fileName.endsWith(".png");
        };
    });
    return pngFiles;
}
```

Comment: I do pass string to it on line 8 before calling listFiles() :/.

Comment: That does not mean that the directory actually exists. I can make File instances to every path I like, even if it does not yet exists. Try call `files.exists()` to test if the directory exists.

Comment: I added code to check if the directory exists before filtering .png files

Comment: I'm sorry to not get back to you. You are right the directory does not exist where I think it should. I am really confused, if I run it as an applet it is fine. If I run it as an application it does not.

Comment: Your path is relative to the currentpath. `System.out.println("currentpath: " +  new File(".").getCanonicalPath());`

Comment: C:\eclipse\workspace\IARL\bin is the path I got. I tried changing the loadFolder input strings to this with no avail "\\data\\tiles\\walls"

Answer (score 0):

try using an absolute path to your directory, not relative

public static File[] wallTiles = loadFolder("data/tiles/walls");

->

public static File[] wallTiles = loadFolder("/whatever_path/data/tiles/walls");

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Stepping through it in debug now